# Unable to call a custom URL scheme on MacOS

Tags: office-js

I am creating a PowerPoint Office-Js addin solution that depends on a native MacOS app running on the same system, which can be launched using a [custom URL scheme](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app) (e.g. MyApp://doSpecificAction).

When I try to open that URL in a browser on MacOs, I get a confirmation prompt then the native app opens successfully. When I try to open the same URL from within the add-in, it doesn't work. Are there certain permissions that I need, and how to do that?

Comment: Please specify what "doesn't work" means. Do you get an error message? In the console, maybe? I suspect that you can't have a custom protocol. It probably has to be HTTPS.

Comment: @RickKirkham it doesn't look like anything is happening or getting logged in the console. I am registering the URL with my Appname:// rather than HTTPS so that it opens my app..

Comment: You could try putting the URL in the [AppDomains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/appdomains) section of the manifest; but I don't think that's going to work. The WebView control that hosts Office add-in's is sandboxed in a number of ways, so it can't do everything that can be done in the standalone browser.